# Building windows executable using pyqt with python embedded

Tags: python, c, pyqt

I'm trying to make a windows application that runs some python code, more or less like what **py2exe** does but made by hand.
My application should run on windows without any external python dependencies (even the interpreter).

I've tested this (**main.cpp**):

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print \"Test\"\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When a build this I get a .exe file which upon execution prints `Test` on the console.
So far so good, but now I'm trying to build a minimal PyQt application as well, for that I put on the same folder of my .exe application the files
**QtGui.pyd**, **QtGui4.dll**, **QtCore.pyd** and **QtCore4.dll**, this is **main.cpp**:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import QtGui as gui\n"
            "\n"
            "app = gui.QApplication([])\n"
            "mw = gui.QMainWindow()\n"
            "mw.show()\n"
            "print \"Test\"\n"
            "app.exec_()");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the built .exe file I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

So I don't know what kind of *initialization* I need to do in order to use the .pyd files.
Finally these are my questions:

- What I'm doing wrong?
- If I need some kind of extra initialization, how could I do that and why it is needed? Maybe it's something inherent to the Qt bindings?
- Should I copy another *pyd file to the working dir of the app?
- Is this approach of using directly the .pyd files feasible? Or there is a better way to make an application like the one I want?

Note: I do not want to use any tool like py2exe, cx_Freeze, pyinstaller, etc. I want to build the app myself.

Comment: I see in my install of PyQt that there is also a `Qt.pyd` file. Maybe you could try adding it to your bundle?

Comment: Ok, I'm currently on linux but I will try it later, thanks